# Variable-size heterogeneous container with type-safe lookup by type

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to implement entity-component system where each *Entity* has a list of components. Each component is derived from *BaseComponent* class. Each component in entity is unique - for example it's impossible for entity to have two *TransformComponent* components. I want to have fast and type safe access to components from entity using method getComponent():

```
template <typename T>
T * getComponent();
```

What would be the best way to implement component container inside entities?

PS: I have a lot of entities (about 10-20 thousands) and each entity has about 2-3 components, 10 is max. So I'am afraid that *unordered_map* is too heavyweight for my task.

Comment: `unordered_map<type_index, unique_ptr<BaseComponent>>`, I guess.

Comment: Why do you need to know the specific child component type? Why can't you use the (possibly abstract) interface in `BaseComponent`?

Comment: I thought about it. But I have a lot of entities (about 10-20 thousands) and each entity has about 2-3 components, 10 is max. Isn't unordered_map is too heavyweight solution for this task?

Comment: To Mark: I need a lot of transformation with entities based on fact that certain component is  inside an entity and edit those components as well

Comment: Have you actually measured the performance of the `unordered_map` version before declaring it "too heavyweight"? The ordered version or a sorted vector are also possible options.

Comment: @Rem: If there are only a handful of components per container, then maybe `vector<pair<...>>`, with a simple linear search, would have less overhead. I'd try both and measure, if speed is important.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest the tuple approach as a strawman to determine what your other requirements are:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename...Components>
class Entity : private Components... {
public:
    Entity() = default;

    Entity(Components...components) :
        Components(std::move(components))... {}

    template <typename T>
    T& get() {
        return *this;
    }
    template <typename T>
    const T& get() const {
        return *this;
    }
};


#include <iostream>

struct ComponentA { void f() const { std::cout << "I'm a ComponentA\n"; } };
struct ComponentB { void f() const { std::cout << "I'm a ComponentB\n"; } };
struct ComponentC { void f() const { std::cout << "I'm a ComponentC\n"; } };

int main() {
    {
        Entity<ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC> e;
        e.get<ComponentC>().f();
        e.get<ComponentB>().f();
        e.get<ComponentA>().f();
    }

    {
        ComponentA a;
        Entity<ComponentA, ComponentB> e{a, {}};
    }

    {
        // error: duplicate base type
        // Entity<ComponentA, ComponentA> invalid_entity;
    }
}
```

It has the advantage that all types are concrete, and the `Component` types need not even be related.

Comment: The tuple is perfect except one thing - it is fixed length container but I need to add and remove components in runtime

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use simple approach to have array *BaseComponent *m_comps[MAX_COMPONENTS]* inside *Entity* and assign unique id for each component type. Because the number of component types is limited to 20-30. This way I will have the fastest access to components with a little overhead of storing 20-30 pointers inside entity (and they will be allocated in one chunk with entity itself allowing good cache locality)

I use this code for type safe access:

```
template <typename T>
T * Entity::getComp()
{
  return (T*)m_comps[T::idCompType];
}
```

and each component should declare const static member *idCompType*